# adding structs into doubly linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

I am new to programming (first semester) and the examples I found here always helped me so much while doing my homeworks!
Now I have to do a slightly bigger project and I've already read so much but I just can't solve the problem.

### What I'm required to do

1. Read data from a text from a file
2. Sort it into a struct via `strtok()`
   (Place it into a struct, by assigning data read from file to struct fields)
3. Add the structs into a **doubly linked list**

### Issues

1. The list has only the first and the last struct in it when I print it, the structs in between disappear (the first entry "head" is defined in the main along with `pNode=head;`)
2. If I try to print the list in forward order, it prints the last list element infinitely.

I have tried to copy only the parts I think are important for the problem.
Since I have already tried so much and I don't even know where to look for the mistake anymore, any help or hint is appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

```
void read_file(struct node *pNode, FILE *fp) {
    struct node *head = pNode;
    head->next=NULL;
    head->prev=NULL;

    /*(fread, strtok_r, strtok,...)*/

    while (token1 != NULL) {
        //allocating memory for the structs
        struct node*new = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
        *new =*pNode;

        while (token2 != NULL) {
            new->index = (*token2 - 48);
            token2 = strtok(NULL, "\n"); //jump to next token (=next line)

            new->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(new->name)+1);
            strcpy(new->name, token2);
            token2 = strtok(NULL, "\n");

            /*(some more sorting into struct)*/

            /*ADD STRUCT TO LIST*/

            if (head->next==NULL){
                head->next=new;
                head->prev=NULL;
                new->prev=head;
                new->next=NULL;
            }

            new->next = head->next;
            head->next = new;
            new->next->prev = new;
            new->prev = head;
            head->prev = NULL;

            pNode=new;
        }

        token_recipe = strtok_r(NULL, "#", &temp); //jump to next token (=next recipe)
    }

    printf("\nLinked list in backwards order:\n");

    while (pNode != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", pNode->name);
        pNode= pNode->prev;
    }
    puts("\n");
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `*new =*pNode` to do?

Comment: This "sort it into a struct" confuses me. You probably mean "sort into an array of structs" or something else involving a larger data structure. Consider rephrasing to reduce the risk to confuse others like me.

Comment: Including a really basic main function will probably help in understanding your issues. Anyway, this coud be the right moment to try a debugger. ;)

Comment: @Yunnosch I've interpreted the _"sort it into a struct"_ phrase as a loose way to say _"Place it into a struct, by assigning data read from file to struct fields"_. Nezuko, Am I correct?

Comment: @Cubo78 I see what you mean, I read "several instances of the same kind of data, to be sorted e.g. alphabetically into ...". But "sort one instance each of different kinds of data into appropriately typed fields of a struct" makes some sense. The point is I managed to misunderstand, and assuming I am not the slowest on the uptake, rephrasing for clarity is probably worth the effort.

Comment: @ChrisTurner pNode contains the first struct (that's initialized in the main), I did this because I thought it helps me with finding the mistakes! :)

Comment: @Yunnosch I just suggested an edit, but in these cases I usually leave these _linguistic sugar_ to native English people. Even in this case I'm not 100% sure of my interpretation.. :)

Comment: @Cubo78 that's what I meant, thank you! Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a messy tangle going on here which I'll try and help unravel.

```
        if (head->next==NULL){
            head->next=new;
            head->prev=NULL;
            new->prev=head;
            new->next=NULL;
        }

        new->next = head->next;
        head->next = new;
        new->next->prev = new;
        new->prev = head;
        head->prev = NULL;
```

The first time around you have `head` and `new`. `head->next` is `NULL` so you do the bit in the `if` block and end up with the list looking like:

> head <-> new

Then you point `new->next` to `head->next`...which means you're pointing `new->next` to `new`.

> head <-> new -> new

`new->next->prev = new` so `new->prev` now also equals `new`

> head -> new <-> new

but then you fix it to point it back to `head` and set `head->prev` to `NULL` which it probably already was as you don't ever change it.

> head <-> new -> new

And you've still got that cycle loop of `new` pointing to itself as the next node.

Scrap that code completely. `pNode` is the previous node in your list and initially is the same as `head` - that's the variable you should be linking to.

```
new->prev = pNode;
pNode->next = new;
```

the previous and next values that aren't specified should already be set to `NULL` (because you're using `calloc`) or pointing to a valid place in memory so you don't need to mess with them.

And then you correctly do the following at the end of the loop

```
pNode = new;
```

to point the end of your list to the latest node created.

You also should get rid of the following line because `new` is a fresh new node - there shouldn't be anything in `pNode` to copy and in doing so, so you're setting the next & previous values which you don't want as they're already correctly set to `NULL`.

```
*new =*pNode;
```